# как сделать такое меню при открытии?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, svg

1. как сделать такое меню при открытии ?
2. https://ecomilk.ru/magazine/healthy-food/chto-takoe-otbornoe-moloko/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуемся anime.js

И так же нарисуем заранее в inkscape два path

1) Начальное состояние - в html

2) Конечное состояние - в js

Находим на cdnjs.com нашу библиотеку: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js

После того как нарисовали пути (path) делаем как в документации ..найти не сложно ссылку давать не буду

Смотрим результат

```js
document.getElementById("evt").onclick = function() {
  let timeline = anime.timeline();

  timeline
    .add({
      targets: "#p1",
      d: {
        value: [
          "M 0,116.41121 H 498.39795 V 297 C 439.30599,258.75657 324.49032,308.69573 266.18937,262.80259 183.05485,197.36103 110.05747,259.17925 66.909094,297 H 0 Z"
        ],
        duration: 1200,
        delay: 0,
        easing: "easeOutQuad"
      }
    });
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#evt {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#evt span {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 4px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>

  <div id="evt">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    </div>

    <svg viewBox = "0 120 500 280" >
    <path d = "m 0,116.41121 h 498.39795 v 0 c -78.74672,0.31014 -154.93393,-1.18124 -216.33358,-2.53124 -102.63168,-2.25656 -67.68547,3.18023 -147.11956,2.44741 L 47.625,117.83929 Z"
  fill = "lightblue"
  id="p1" />
    </svg>
```